# How do I run a global command with same name as a file in the working directory on windows?

Tags: windows, command-line, command

I want to run a command that is installed and available globally on my cmd.exe commandline.

This usually works fine, except when I run it in a directory that has a file with the same name as the command.

So any time I use this command in this particular directory my windows is trying to open this file in whatever application is registered for this extension.

It is very annoying, but there must be a way around this right?

I tried it with a bunch of names, like ping.txt and they all open the files intead of running the command.

Answer (score 1):

That's not normal behaviour in the default configuration; sounds like the `PATHEXT` environment variable has been modified.

You could either change it back to the default,

```
PATHEXT=.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC
```

or explicitly type `ping.exe` (for example) instead of just `ping`.

Answer (score 0):

If the file name is EXACTLY the same (including the same extension, i.e. ".exe"), then I believe the only way around this is to specify the full path to the file you WANT to execute.  For example, if the program you want to execute is explorer.exe, but you have a file named explorer.exe in your current directory, you have to specify \Windows\explorer.exe to run Windows explorer.